# What is the best practice for synchronizing parallel API requests to return the same result from a long running query without multiple executions?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, rx-java2, completable-future

I'm working on a backend Spring Boot project which is called by multiple clients. One of the functionalities is to merge data from two different databases and return the result, which may take up to 2 minutes.

I would like to be able to make concurrent calls to this endpoint wait for an already running request and return the same result without running the query again.

As shown below I've tried to setup a CompletableFuture field in the service singleton bean (which I know is a code smell since singleton service beans should be stateless).

```java
//RestController
    @Async
    @GetMapping
    public CompletableFuture<List<Foo>> getSyncedFoo() {
        return service.syncFoo();
    }

//ServiceImpl

    private CompletableFuture<List<Foo>> syncTask;

    @Override
    @Async
    @Transactional
    public CompletableFuture<List<Foo>> syncFoo() {
        if (this.syncTask == null || this.syncTask.isDone()) {
            this.syncTask = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
                // long running task
                return new ArrayList<>();
            });
        }
        return this.dbaseSyncTask;
    }
```

I expected multiple frontend clients calling the api endpoint to receive the same response at roughly the same time, resulting in the backend performing the long running operation just once.

The operation was in fact executed just once but one of the clients received a 503 (Service Unavailable) while the other client received the expected response.

I suspect it's due to the shared use of the CompletableFuture, but I'm at a loss on what approach I should take. Could RxJava be of any use with the Observable strategy?

Comment: I think Concurrency in practice by Brian Goetz has code example for exactly this problem

Comment: You might want to see my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54076937/1763035). It's adaptable to a single request and storing the result of the first.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a functional answer, for now.

```
@Service
public class FooServiceImpl implements FooService {

    private CompletableFuture<List<Foo>> syncFuture;
    private Observable<List<Foo>> syncObservable;

    @Override
    public Single<List<Foo>> syncFoo() {
        if (syncFuture == null || syncFuture .isDone()) {
            syncFuture = syncFooAsync();
            syncObservable = Observable.fromFuture(syncFuture).share();
        }
        return Single.fromObservable(syncObservable);
    }

    private CompletableFuture<List<Foo>> syncFooAsync() {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10_000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                return new ArrayList<>();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

By using the RxJava library it s possible to multicast the created observable to multiple listeners using **Observable::share** method and the @RestController will happily work with the returned Single(s).

Sadly it still uses state in a singleton which is accessed concurrently by multiple threads so I fear situations where concurrency issues like the Observable completing while a new request is still in the process of creating a new subscription.

Hence I do not recommend this as a best practice so I'm not marking this as a final answer.